# solr fieldType definition for processing multi-part word field value

Tags: solr

i have solr in my application and i need to cover the following scenario:
i have a field  with three values:
coffee shops
Donut shops
sports shops

the problem that when i search for "coffee shops" i get all documents having the any of the above  values. the reason is that all have "shops" in them.
i am trying to change this search behavior so that when i search for "coffee shops" i get documents having "coffee shops" only and when i search for "shops" i get documents having all the above values. below is my fieldType definition

```
  <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                splitOnNumerics="0"
                stemEnglishPossessive="1"
                splitOnCaseChange="1"
                generateWordParts="1"
                generateNumberParts="1"
                catenateWords="1"
                catenateNumbers="1"
                catenateAll="0"
                preserveOriginal="1"                
                protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" 
                ignoreCase="true" 
                words="stopwords.txt" 
                enablePositionIncrements="true" /> 
        <filter class="solr.HunspellStemFilterFactory"
                dictionary="en_US.dic"
                affix="en_US.aff"
                ignoreCase="true" />       
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">        
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>        
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                splitOnNumerics="0"
                stemEnglishPossessive="1"
                splitOnCaseChange="1"
                generateWordParts="1"
                generateNumberParts="1"
                catenateWords="0"
                catenateNumbers="0"
                catenateAll="0"
                preserveOriginal="1"                
                protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" 
                ignoreCase="true" 
                words="stopwords.txt" 
                enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <filter class="solr.HunspellStemFilterFactory"
                dictionary="en_US.dic"
                affix="en_US.aff"
                ignoreCase="true" />
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

thank you

Comment: I think the safer thing to do would be to just boost the results containing the full phrase above other matches, in addition to using ANDing by default. The exact behavior you describe should require double quotes in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

It seems I had the same need, with a search for `sac à main` (`handbag` in french) returning content with only `sac`, which I didn't want. But I wanted searches for `sac` to return content with `sac à main`.

Here is what I did after several hours of research on the Web:

In `schema.xml`, at least these parameters:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    …
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory"
      synonyms="fr_expressions.txt"
      ignoreCase="true"
      expand="true" />
    …
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    …
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory"
      synonyms="fr_expressions.txt"
      ignoreCase="true"
      expand="false" />
    …
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

In `fr_expressions.txt`, lines such as this one:

```
sac_a_main,sac a main,sacs a main
```

The `index` analyzer will replace any of the 3 values in the indexed text with all of them.

The `query` analyzer will replace any of the 3 values in the query with `sac_a_main`.

A search for `sac à main` will then find only content that have `sac_a_main`, but a search for `sac` will also find these contents along with others.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

In the schema.xml there's a default operator which defaults to OR.
However, it's said not to rely on that (although i'd change it to AND).

Suppose you are searching in the "Description" field, you can do:

**Description:"coffee shops"**  <<< This is an exact match (case ignored), in the exact order (with no separation, i think)
**Description:(coffe shops)**   <<< This will match description containing both words, in any order (with any distance, i think)

Comment: i already set the default operator to AND. the thing is that i have a default search filed (defaultSearchField) composed of 25 other fields generated using the <copyField>. so i can't explicitly set the filed i am search against because my query should check against the defaultSearchField and return all the valid documents of the search. the thing that when i search for "coffee shops" i should only get coffee shops; when i search for "Donut shops" i also should get only Donut shops; but when i search for "shops" i should get both. i tried different fieldType configurations but didnt work.

Comment: come on stackoverflowers, no one came across such an issue?? appreciate the help